# Decrypting encrypted assertion using SAML 2.0 in java using OpenSAML

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, saml-2.0, opensaml

I have a problem while trying to decrypt encrypted assertion using SAML 2.0. The library I am using is OpenSAML Java libraries 2.5.2.

The encrypted assertion looks like this:

```
<EncryptedAssertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
<enc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" 
    xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
  <enc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
  <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <e:EncryptionMethod 
       Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
      </e:EncryptionMethod>
      <KeyInfo>
        <o:SecurityTokenReference 
           xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-
                    1.0.xsd">
          <o:KeyIdentifier 
            ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-
                      1.1#ThumbprintSHA1"
            EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-
                      message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
          1H3mV/pJAlVZAst/Dt0rqbBd67g=
          </o:KeyIdentifier>
        </o:SecurityTokenReference>
      </KeyInfo>
      <e:CipherData>
        <e:CipherValue>
   ... ENCRYPTED KEY HERE ...
        </e:CipherValue>
      </e:CipherData>
    </e:EncryptedKey>
  </KeyInfo>
  <enc:CipherData>
    <enc:CipherValue>
    ... ENCRYPTED ASSERTIONS HERE ...
    </enc:CipherValue>
  </enc:CipherData>
</enc:EncryptedData>
</EncryptedAssertion>
```

I did convert my private key that is in PEM format to pkcs8 format using the following openssl command:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -inform PEM -in rsa_private_key.key -outform DER -out rsa_private_key.pk8
```

I am then ready to try to decrypt the encrypted assertion. Here is my Java code:

```
...
// Load the XML file and parse it.
File xmlFile = new File("data\\token.xml");
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
Document document = parserPoolManager.parse(inputStream);
Element metadataRoot = document.getDocumentElement();

// Unmarshall
UnmarshallerFactory unmarshallerFactory = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory();
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = unmarshallerFactory.getUnmarshaller(metadataRoot);
EncryptedAssertion encryptedAssertion = (EncryptedAssertion)unmarshaller.unmarshall(metadataRoot);

// Load the private key file.
File privateKeyFile = new File("data\\rsa_private_key.pk8");
FileInputStream inputStreamPrivateKey = new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile);
byte[] encodedPrivateKey = new byte[(int)privateKeyFile.length()];
inputStreamPrivateKey.read(encodedPrivateKey);
inputStreamPrivateKey.close();

// Create the private key.
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedPrivateKey);
RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey)KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

// Create the credentials.
BasicX509Credential decryptionCredential = new BasicX509Credential();
decryptionCredential.setPrivateKey(privateKey);

// Create a decrypter.
Decrypter decrypter = new Decrypter(null, new StaticKeyInfoCredentialResolver(decryptionCredential), new InlineEncryptedKeyResolver());

// Decrypt the assertion.
Assertion decryptedAssertion;

try
{
    decryptedAssertion = decrypter.decrypt(encryptedAssertion);
}
...
```

Running this code always results as being unable to decrypt the assertion. I do get the following errors:

```
5473 [main] ERROR org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter - Error decrypting encrypted key
org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLEncryptionException: Key is too long for unwrapping
Original Exception was java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key is too long for unwrapping
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.decryptKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:681)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:612)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptUsingResolvedEncryptedKey(Decrypter.java:762)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:513)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToList(Decrypter.java:440)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:401)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:141)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decrypt(Decrypter.java:69)
    at DecrypterTool.main(DecrypterTool.java:121)
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key is too long for unwrapping
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineUnwrap(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.unwrap(DashoA13*..)
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.decryptKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:681)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:612)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptUsingResolvedEncryptedKey(Decrypter.java:762)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:513)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToList(Decrypter.java:440)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:401)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:141)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decrypt(Decrypter.java:69)
    at DecrypterTool.main(DecrypterTool.java:121)
5477 [main] ERROR org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter - Failed to decrypt EncryptedKey, valid decryption key could not be resolved
5477 [main] ERROR org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter - Failed to decrypt EncryptedData using either EncryptedData KeyInfoCredentialResolver or EncryptedKeyResolver + EncryptedKey KeyInfoCredentialResolver
5478 [main] ERROR org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter - SAML Decrypter encountered an error decrypting element content
org.opensaml.xml.encryption.DecryptionException: Failed to decrypt EncryptedData
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:524)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToList(Decrypter.java:440)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:401)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:141)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decrypt(Decrypter.java:69)
    at DecrypterTool.main(DecrypterTool.java:121)
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong in this case. I converted my private key to pkcs8, I loaded my SAML XML data and unmarshalled it into the valid type (EncryptedAssertion) and I created a decrypted based on my private key.

Is it possible that it is related to the oaep format for RSA? I'm using the default java cryptography library.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not know your exact problem but I had bang my head while dealing with [tag:saml] I found great ease by using `apache camel`.

Comment: @Shahzeb I would love to use something else, but my client is using saml and I can't really change that. :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For those of you who will get this problem, it was related to the fact that the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files was not installed and it was not letting me use encryption better than AES-128. Replacing the policy files with the JCE policy files, I was able to successfully decrypt my encrypted assertion.

Comment: Mind sharing how you arrived at this finding?

Answer (score 3):

Agree with @thwalrusnp. Just wanted to add the exact location from where you can download the policy jars.

Found it on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31987381/201514) to [Error while decrypting assertion sent from IDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31987116/error-while-decrypting-assertion-sent-from-idp)

> This happens due to limitation of cryptography strength in default
>   distribution of Java Runtime Environment.
>
> 1. Download Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files ([for Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)) ([for Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html))
> 2. Extract zip archive and find there `local_policy.jar` and `US_export_policy.jar`.
> 3. Replace your JRE version of these files under $JAVA_HOME/jre{version_number}/lib/security/ with downloaded ones.
> 4. Restart JRE process, if any running. Now you can use longer keys.

Comment: Adding to this, it looks like the unlimited strength policy files are shipped by default with Java 9.

Comment: @user+ 9 up and also 8u161 up have unlimited policy builtin. See this better oracle page: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce-all-downloads.html .