# Key too long for unwrapping

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rsa

I am making a PGP program for a school class, however I am having some trouble unwrapping and wrapping keys. I am encrypting the text with a random aes key, then wrapping the aes key with the private key from the KeyPair. To decrypt, I am unwrapping the aes key with the public key from the KeyPair, however I am getting the **Key is too long for unwrapping** error. I checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237273/spring-saml-key-is-too-long-for-unwrapping-invalidkeyexception), but I am pretty sure I am using the correct keys to unwrap and wrap. Here is my code for wrapping and unwrapping

```
byte[] returnWrappedKey(Key keyToWrap, Key keyForWrapping) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, keyForWrapping);
    return cipher.wrap(keyToWrap);
}
Key returnUnwrappedKey(byte[] keyToUnwrap, Key keyForUnwrapping) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, keyForUnwrapping);
    return cipher.unwrap(keyToUnwrap, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);
}
```

I pass in the public or private keyFor(Un)Wrapping, yet whichever way I do it I get the error. I am using swing to have the user input a key, and `.getBytes()` to get the key for unwrapping.

Full code **(Not sure if this is helpful)**

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.*;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import java.util.*;

public class run {
    /**
     * Variable State meaning
     * 1: Key is Public
     * 2: Key is Private
     * 3: Key is not defined as either public or private
     */
    static int keyState = 3;
    static int AESKeyState = 3;
    static byte[] operationBytes;
    static PublicKey operationalPubKey;
    static PrivateKey operationalPrvKey;
    static Key operationalAESKey;
    static final gui window = new gui();
    static rsaEncryption rsaMethods = new rsaEncryption();
    static aesEncryption aesMethods = new aesEncryption();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        window.createSignature.addActionListener(e -> {
            KeyPair pair = null;
            try {
                pair = rsaMethods.generateKeyPair();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException noSuchAlgorithmException) {
                displayError(noSuchAlgorithmException);
            }
            assert pair != null;
            window.publicKeyOutputArea.setText(rsaMethods.generatePublicKeyString(pair.getPublic()));
            window.privateKeyOutputArea.setText(rsaMethods.generatePrivateKeyString(pair.getPrivate()));
        });
        window.copyPublicKeyToClipboard.addActionListener(e -> rsaMethods.copyDataToClipboard(window.publicKeyOutputArea.getText()));
        window.copyPrivateKeyToClipboard.addActionListener(e -> rsaMethods.copyDataToClipboard(window.privateKeyOutputArea.getText()));
        window.exportPublicKeyToFile.addActionListener(e -> {
            int choice = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                try {
                    rsaMethods.exportDataToFile(fileChooser.getSelectedFile(), window.publicKeyOutputArea.getText());
                } catch (IOException ioException) {
                    displayError(ioException);
                }
            }
        });
        window.exportPrivateKeyToFile.addActionListener(e -> {
            int choice = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                try {
                    rsaMethods.exportDataToFile(fileChooser.getSelectedFile(), window.privateKeyOutputArea.getText());
                } catch (IOException ioException) {
                    displayError(ioException);
                }
            }
        });
        window.importPublicKeyFromFile.addActionListener(e -> {
            PublicKey publicKey = null;
            int choice = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                try {
                    publicKey = rsaMethods.getPublicKeyFromFile(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException | InvalidKeySpecException noSuchAlgorithmException) {
                    displayError(noSuchAlgorithmException);
                }
            }
            assert publicKey != null;
            window.pasteKeyForOperation.setText(rsaMethods.generatePublicKeyString(publicKey));
            keyState = 1;
        });
        window.importPrivateKeyFromFile.addActionListener(e -> {
            PrivateKey privateKey = null;
            int choice = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                try {
                    privateKey = rsaMethods.getPrivateKeyFromFile(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
                } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException ioException) {
                    displayError(ioException);
                }
            }
            assert privateKey != null;
            window.pasteKeyForOperation.setText(rsaMethods.generatePrivateKeyString(privateKey));
            keyState = 2;
        });
        window.checkKey.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (keyState == 3 && window.pasteKeyForOperation.getText().equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have not input a valid key!");
            } else {
                if (window.publicKeyPasteSelection.isSelected()) {
                    try {
                        operationalPubKey = rsaMethods.getPubKeyFromString(window.pasteKeyForOperation.getText());
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException noSuchAlgorithmException) {
                        displayError(noSuchAlgorithmException);
                    }
                    keyState = 1;
                    window.pasteKeyForOperation.setText("");
                    AESKeyState = 3;
                } else if (window.privateKeyPasteSelection.isSelected()) {
                    try {
                        operationalPrvKey = rsaMethods.getPrvKeyFromString(window.pasteKeyForOperation.getText());
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException noSuchAlgorithmException) {
                        displayError(noSuchAlgorithmException);
                    }
                    keyState = 2;
                    window.pasteKeyForOperation.setText("");
                    AESKeyState = 3;
                }
            }
        });
        window.checkAESKey.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (keyState == 3) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You need to first input a RSA Key and select public or private!");
            } else if (Objects.equals(window.pasteKeyForOperation.getText(), "")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have not input a key!");
            } else if (keyState == 1) {
                try {
                    operationalAESKey = rsaMethods.returnUnwrappedKey(window.pasteKeyForOperation.getText().getBytes(), operationalPubKey);
                } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException ex) {
                    displayError(ex);
                }
                AESKeyState = 1;
            } else if (keyState == 2) {
                try {
                    operationalAESKey = rsaMethods.returnUnwrappedKey(window.pasteKeyForOperation.getText().getBytes(), operationalPrvKey);
                } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException ex) {
                    displayError(ex);
                }
                AESKeyState = 2;
            }
        });
        window.operationDataFileImport.addActionListener(e -> {
            int choice = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                window.operationPlainTextInput.setText("Data received from file import");
            }
            try {
                operationBytes = rsaMethods.importDataFromFile(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                displayError(ioException);
            }
        });
        window.encryptDataButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (operationBytes == null) {
                operationBytes = window.operationPlainTextInput.getText().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            }
            try {
                encryptData();
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchProviderException noSuchPaddingException) {
                displayError(noSuchPaddingException);
            }
        });
        window.decryptDataButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (operationBytes == null) {
                operationBytes = window.operationPlainTextInput.getText().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            }
            try {
                decryptData();
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | NoSuchPaddingException | BadPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchProviderException illegalBlockSizeException) {
                displayError(illegalBlockSizeException);
            }
        });
        window.operationDataFileExport.addActionListener(e -> {
            int choice = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                try {
                    rsaMethods.exportDataToFile(fileChooser.getSelectedFile(), window.operationPlainTextOutput.getText());
                } catch (IOException ioException) {
                    displayError(ioException);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Sets the plain text output of the operationPlainTextOutput
     * panel to the decrypted or encrypted data encoded in
     * Base64 using the key input from the user.
     *
     * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException Throws IllegalBlockSizeException.
     * @throws NoSuchPaddingException Throws NoSuchPaddingException.
     * @throws BadPaddingException Throws BadPaddingException.
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException Throws NoSuchAlgorithmException.
     * @throws InvalidKeyException Throws InvalidKeyException.
     */
    private static void encryptData() throws NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException {
        operationBytes = window.operationPlainTextInput.getText().getBytes();
        SecretKey key = aesMethods.returnKey();
        window.operationPlainTextOutput.setText(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(aesMethods.returnEncryptedData(operationBytes, key)));
        if (keyState == 1) {
            byte[] bKey = rsaMethods.returnWrappedKey(key, operationalPubKey);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your AES key (RSA PUB KEY) has been copied to your clipboard!");
            rsaMethods.copyDataToClipboard(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bKey));
            keyState = 3;
        } else if (keyState == 2) {
            byte[] bKey = rsaMethods.returnWrappedKey(key, operationalPrvKey);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your AES key (RSA PRV KEY) has been copied to your clipboard!");
            rsaMethods.copyDataToClipboard(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bKey));
            keyState = 3;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have not input a key!");
        }
    }
    private static void decryptData() throws NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException {
        operationBytes = window.operationPlainTextInput.getText().getBytes();
        Key key = operationalAESKey;
        if (AESKeyState == 1 || AESKeyState == 2) {
            window.operationPlainTextOutput.setText(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(aesMethods.returnDecryptedData(window.operationPlainTextInput.getText().getBytes(), key)));
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have not input a AES key!");
        }
    }
    private static void displayError(@NotNull Exception e) {
        System.out.println(keyState);
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
}

class rsaEncryption {
    KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        generator.initialize(2048, random);
        return generator.generateKeyPair();
    }
    PublicKey getPublicKeyFromFile(@NotNull File file) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        return KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath())));
    }
    PrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromFile(@NotNull File file) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        return KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath())));
    }
    void copyDataToClipboard(String string) {
        StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(string);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(selection, null);
    }
    String generatePrivateKeyString(@NotNull PrivateKey privateKey) {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(privateKey.getEncoded());
    }
    String generatePublicKeyString(@NotNull PublicKey publicKey) {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded());
    }
    byte[] returnWrappedKey(Key keyToWrap, Key keyForWrapping) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, keyForWrapping);
        return cipher.wrap(keyToWrap);
    }
    Key returnUnwrappedKey(byte[] keyToUnwrap, Key keyForUnwrapping) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, keyForUnwrapping);
        return cipher.unwrap(keyToUnwrap, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);
    }
    byte[] importDataFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        return fis.readAllBytes();
    }
    void exportDataToFile(File file, String string) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        writer.write(string);
        writer.flush();
    }
    PublicKey getPubKeyFromString(String string) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(string);
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return factory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes));
    }
    PrivateKey getPrvKeyFromString(String string) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(string);
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return factory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes));
    }
}
class aesEncryption {
    SecretKey returnKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyGenerator gen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        gen.init(new SecureRandom());
        return gen.generateKey();
    }
    byte[] returnEncryptedData(byte[] data, Key key) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }
    byte[] returnDecryptedData(byte[] data, Key key) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        return  cipher.doFinal(data);
    }
}

class gui {
    public gui() {
        initialize();
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton createSignature = new JButton("Create!");
    JTextArea privateKeyOutputArea = new JTextArea();
    JTextArea publicKeyOutputArea = new JTextArea();
    JButton exportPublicKeyToFile = new JButton("Export Key to File");
    JButton copyPublicKeyToClipboard = new JButton("Copy Key to Clipboard");
    JButton exportPrivateKeyToFile = new JButton("Export Key to File");
    JButton copyPrivateKeyToClipboard = new JButton("Copy Key to Clipboard");
    JButton importPublicKeyFromFile = new JButton("PubKey");
    JButton importPrivateKeyFromFile = new JButton("PrvKey");
    JRadioButton publicKeyPasteSelection = new JRadioButton("PUBLIC KEY");
    JRadioButton privateKeyPasteSelection = new JRadioButton("PRIVATE KEY");
    JTextField pasteKeyForOperation = new JTextField();
    JTextArea operationPlainTextInput = new JTextArea();
    JTextArea operationPlainTextOutput = new JTextArea();
    JButton encryptDataButton = new JButton("Encrypt");
    JButton decryptDataButton = new JButton("Decrypt");
    JButton operationDataFileImport = new JButton("Import Data From File");
    JButton operationDataFileExport = new JButton("Export Data To File");
    JButton checkKey = new JButton("Check Key");
    JButton checkAESKey = new JButton("AES Key");

    private void initialize() {
        frame.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 12));
        frame.setTitle("RSA SIGNATURE MANAGER");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 619, 495);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel signatureCreationPanel = new JPanel();
        signatureCreationPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Create New Signature", null, signatureCreationPanel, null);
        signatureCreationPanel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel createNewPgpSignature = new JLabel("Create New PGP Signature");
        createNewPgpSignature.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        createNewPgpSignature.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 24));
        createNewPgpSignature.setBounds(10, 11, 391, 30);
        signatureCreationPanel.add(createNewPgpSignature);

        createSignature.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        createSignature.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        createSignature.setBounds(379, 17, 188, 23);
        signatureCreationPanel.add(createSignature);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(privateKeyOutputArea);
        scrollPane.setBounds(306, 103, 282, 282);
        privateKeyOutputArea.setEditable(false);
        privateKeyOutputArea.add(new JScrollBar());
        privateKeyOutputArea.setLineWrap(true);
        privateKeyOutputArea.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        privateKeyOutputArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        privateKeyOutputArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        signatureCreationPanel.add(scrollPane);

        publicKeyOutputArea.setEditable(false);
        publicKeyOutputArea.setLineWrap(true);
        publicKeyOutputArea.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        publicKeyOutputArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        publicKeyOutputArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        publicKeyOutputArea.setBounds(10, 103, 286, 282);
        signatureCreationPanel.add(publicKeyOutputArea);

        exportPublicKeyToFile.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        exportPublicKeyToFile.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        exportPublicKeyToFile.setBounds(10, 396, 136, 23);
        signatureCreationPanel.add(exportPublicKeyToFile);

        copyPublicKeyToClipboard.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        copyPublicKeyToClipboard.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        copyPublicKeyToClipboard.setBounds(156, 396, 140, 23);
        signatureCreationPanel.add(copyPublicKeyToClipboard);

        exportPrivateKeyToFile.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        exportPrivateKeyToFile.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        exportPrivateKeyToFile.setBounds(306, 396, 136, 23);
        signatureCreationPanel.add(exportPrivateKeyToFile);

        copyPrivateKeyToClipboard.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        copyPrivateKeyToClipboard.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        copyPrivateKeyToClipboard.setBounds(448, 396, 140, 23);
        signatureCreationPanel.add(copyPrivateKeyToClipboard);

        JLabel publicKeyCreationContext = new JLabel("Public Key:");
        publicKeyCreationContext.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        publicKeyCreationContext.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 16));
        publicKeyCreationContext.setBounds(10, 69, 136, 23);
        signatureCreationPanel.add(publicKeyCreationContext);

        JLabel privateKeyCreationContext = new JLabel("Private Key:");
        privateKeyCreationContext.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        privateKeyCreationContext.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 16));
        privateKeyCreationContext.setBounds(306, 69, 136, 23);
        signatureCreationPanel.add(privateKeyCreationContext);

        JPanel operationPanel = new JPanel();
        operationPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Encrypt or Decrypt", null, operationPanel, null);
        operationPanel.setLayout(null);

        importPublicKeyFromFile.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 18));
        importPublicKeyFromFile.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        importPublicKeyFromFile.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        importPublicKeyFromFile.setBounds(10, 11, 100, 26);
        operationPanel.add(importPublicKeyFromFile);

        importPrivateKeyFromFile.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 18));
        importPrivateKeyFromFile.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        importPrivateKeyFromFile.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        importPrivateKeyFromFile.setBounds(120, 11, 100, 26);
        operationPanel.add(importPrivateKeyFromFile);

        pasteKeyForOperation.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        pasteKeyForOperation.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        pasteKeyForOperation.setToolTipText("Paste Key Here");
        pasteKeyForOperation.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        pasteKeyForOperation.setBounds(230, 11, 200, 26);
        operationPanel.add(pasteKeyForOperation);

        privateKeyPasteSelection.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        privateKeyPasteSelection.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        privateKeyPasteSelection.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        privateKeyPasteSelection.setBounds(170, 40, 125, 26);
        operationPanel.add(privateKeyPasteSelection);

        publicKeyPasteSelection.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        publicKeyPasteSelection.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        publicKeyPasteSelection.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        publicKeyPasteSelection.setBounds(290, 40, 150, 26);
        operationPanel.add(publicKeyPasteSelection);

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(privateKeyPasteSelection);
        group.add(publicKeyPasteSelection);

        checkKey.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        checkKey.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        checkKey.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 18));
        checkKey.setBounds(440, 11, 140, 26);
        operationPanel.add(checkKey);

        checkAESKey.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        checkAESKey.setForeground(Color.white);
        checkAESKey.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 18));
        checkAESKey.setBounds(440, 39, 140, 26);
        operationPanel.add(checkAESKey);

        JScrollPane operationInputScrollPane = new JScrollPane(operationPlainTextInput);
        operationInputScrollPane.setBounds(10, 102, 280, 256);
        operationPlainTextInput.setLineWrap(true);
        operationPlainTextInput.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        operationPlainTextInput.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        operationPanel.add(operationInputScrollPane);

        JScrollPane operationOutputScrollPane = new JScrollPane(operationPlainTextOutput);
        operationOutputScrollPane.setBounds(308, 102, 280, 256);
        operationPlainTextOutput.setLineWrap(true);
        operationPlainTextOutput.setEditable(false);
        operationPlainTextOutput.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        operationPlainTextOutput.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        operationPanel.add(operationOutputScrollPane);

        JLabel whereToPasteDataLabel = new JLabel("Paste data here:");
        whereToPasteDataLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        whereToPasteDataLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        whereToPasteDataLabel.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 14));
        whereToPasteDataLabel.setBounds(20, 78, 142, 14);
        operationPanel.add(whereToPasteDataLabel);

        JLabel operationOutputLabel = new JLabel("Output in Plaintext:");
        operationOutputLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        operationOutputLabel.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 14));
        operationOutputLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        operationOutputLabel.setBounds(319, 78, 250, 14);
        operationPanel.add(operationOutputLabel);

        encryptDataButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        encryptDataButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        encryptDataButton.setBounds(257, 369, 89, 23);
        operationPanel.add(encryptDataButton);

        decryptDataButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        decryptDataButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        decryptDataButton.setBounds(257, 396, 89, 23);
        operationPanel.add(decryptDataButton);

        operationDataFileImport.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        operationDataFileImport.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        operationDataFileImport.setBounds(10, 369, 170, 23);
        operationPanel.add(operationDataFileImport);

        operationDataFileExport.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        operationDataFileExport.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        operationDataFileExport.setBounds(436, 369, 152, 23);
        operationPanel.add(operationDataFileExport);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's best not to call it PGP, which most people would take as a reference to code that complies with the OpenPGP standard. Also, you must encrypt with the recipient's public key, not theirs or yours private key.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks Mr. President, I will change that