# OpenSAML 3 unmarshaller is null

Tags: java, unmarshalling, opensaml

Hi i am currently porting an app to opensaml3 and run into the following issue:

```
InitializationService.initialize();
...
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory().getUnmarshaller(qName);
```

I have replaced the DefaultBootstrap from opensaml2 and previous by the initialize function. Still the factory is returning me null as marshaller.
Any idea what is going wrong here?

This is the output from initialize progress:

```
[main] INFO org.opensaml.core.config.InitializationService - Initializing OpenSAML using the Java Services API
[main] INFO org.opensaml.xmlsec.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry - Algorithm failed runtime support check, will not be usable: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#ripemd160
[main] INFO org.opensaml.xmlsec.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry - Algorithm failed runtime support check, will not be usable: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-ripemd160
[main] INFO org.opensaml.xmlsec.algorithm.AlgorithmRegistry - Algorithm failed runtime support check, will not be usable: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-ripemd160
```

Answer (score 4):

I supose you're using opensaml v3
so You should create the UnmarshallerFactory object with the XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport class like this it works perfectly

```
UnmarshallerFactory umFactory=XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getUnmarshallerFactory();
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller=umFactory.getUnmarshaller(element);
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is due to lack of algorithm support in your JCE implementation you use. Even if you use BouncyCastle, some algorithms seems to be not supported. Unless you use these algorithms, there is no need to worry about. Installing the JCE unlimited strength jurisdiction policy jars to the jre will resolve this.
Refer: [Decrypting encrypted assertion using SAML 2.0 in java using OpenSAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9422545/235273) as well.