# Working Maven project into jar or extracted opensaml 3 dependencies will result in org.opensaml.core.xml.io.Marshaller is null

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, opensaml

I have a maven (m2e eclipse) project with these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-messaging-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-profile-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-saml-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-security-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-soap-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-storage-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-xmlsec-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-saml-impl</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmltooling</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Inside Eclipse i run `mvn install -U` and everything works fine.

**OLD**
.............................

So i used Maven Dependency Plugin to extract all the jars from the dependencies and used them in another project.

In this Project, when i enter:

```
InitializationService.initialize();
```

I became this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.CryptoBinaryBuilder cannot be cast to org.opensaml.core.xml.XMLObjectBuilder
at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.initializeObjectProviders(XMLConfigurator.java:238)
at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:203)
at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:188)
at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:162)
at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.AbstractXMLObjectProviderInitializer.init(AbstractXMLObjectProviderInitializer.java:52)
at org.opensaml.core.config.InitializationService.initialize(InitializationService.java:56)
```

Update: I could fix this problem by deleting the complete maven repository

**Updated**
................................

So then i used Maven Assembly Plugin to generate a jar with all dependencies included. I can pass the `InitializationService.initialize()`fine, but i am getting a NullPointerException at:

```
marshaller = XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getMarshallerFactory().getMarshaller(authnRequest.getElementQName());
```

Null is returned from the factory.

Related: [OpenSAML 3 unmarshaller is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508448/opensaml-3-unmarshaller-is-null)

Why does my program work when run inside a maven test but not when i use the jar or the code with the dependend libraries?

Comment: Facing the same issue (works within Eclipse but not when running a bundled jar from Maven assembly plugin). Any findings?